# How can I update HKEYS field if there eixists in redis using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, redis-cli

I am using ruby 2.5.1. I did store keys in redis using [HKEYS](https://redis.io/commands/hkeys) and filter keys using [HSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/hscan). I need to modify HKEYS if the key already exists.

How can I update HKEYS field if there exists in redis using Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using ruby code but don't think it's a good idea to use HKEYS

```
require 'redis'
redis = Redis.new 
redis.hset('hash_name', 'key' , 'new_value')if redis.hexists('hash_name','key')
```

or using scan

```
curser , result =  redis.hscan 'hash_name' 
k,val = result.find{ |arr| arr.first == 'k'}
redis.hset('hash_name', 'key' , 'new_value') if k 
# you will need to loop until curser be 0
```

seems inefficient but it works